# NameError when importing a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a script where I want to import a dict from a file and then use it to execute functions.

The file `codes.py` is as follows:

```
rf_433mhz = {
        "0x471d5c" : sensor_LaundryDoor,
}
```

And the file it's using is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mosquitto
import json
import time

def sensor_LaundryDoor():
        print "Laundry Door Opened"
        mqttc.publish("actuators", json.dumps(["switch_HallLight", "on"]))

from codes import rf_433mhz
```

but I'm getting a `NameError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensors.py", line 11, in <module>
    from codes import rf_433mhz
  File "/root/ha/modules/processing/codes.py", line 2, in <module>
    "0x471d5c" : sensor_LaundryDoor,
NameError: name 'sensor_LaundryDoor' is not defined
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? It seems to be getting stuck on not having the function inside `codes.py`

I'm trying to call `sensor_LaundryDoor()` as follows

```
def on_message(msg):
        inbound = json.loads(msg.payload)
        medium = inbound[0]
        content = inbound[1]

        if str(medium) == "433mhz":
                try:
                        rf_433mhz[str(content)]()
                except:
                        print "Sorry code " + content + " is not setup"
```

Comment: You should either define the `sensor_LaundryDoor` in the `codes.py` file, before its use, *or* import the file that defines it. The latter however will create a cyclic import which means you are probably diving the code into files in the wrong way.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the rf_433mhz dict out of the main file

Comment: *Why*? I believe you fell victim of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Mainly to keep the codes out of source control as it is a security risk

Comment: No it isn't. That's called [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and *it doesn't work*. Also, if someone has access to `main.py` why wouldn't it have access to the data file also? The correct way is to encrypt the codes and put the *encrypted text* into the source files.

Comment: out of source control. as in so the codes don't get committed to a public git repository. They're fine on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your dictionary that you're importing, you're setting the value of `0x471d5c` to a variable that was either not defined, or not defined in that scope.

An example of this would be like:

Codes.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
sensor_LaundryDoor = 'foo'

rf_433mhz = {
        "0x471d5c" : sensor_LaundryDoor,
}
```

Main files

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from test import rf_433mhz

print rf_433mhz["0x471d5c"]
```

Comment: The `global` declaration is **utterly useless** used like that. In particular any `global` declaration outside a function definition does *not* do anything.

Comment: Thanks i've moved the function definitions into codes.py - it makes more sense that way anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

`import` isn't `include`. It won't dump the source code of codes.py into your script; rather, it runs codes.py in its own namespace, almost like a separate script, and then assigns either the module object or specific module contents to names in the namespace the import is in. In the namespace of codes.py, there is no `sensor_LaundryDoor` variable.

The way you're dividing the code into modules isn't very useful. To understand codes.py, you need to understand the other file to know what `sensor_LaundryDoor` is. To understand the other file, you need to understand codes.py to know what you're importing. This circular dependency would negate most of the benefit of modularizing your code even if it wasn't an error. Reorganize your code to fix the circular dependency, and you'll probably fix the `NameError` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are hacky ways to solve this but it looks like the real issue is that you're trying to write C-style code in Python. The Python way to do things would be to import  `sensor_LaundryDoor` in `codes.py` before using it, and if this introduces a circular reference then that's a design issue.

Maybe you need three modules, `events.py` with your main loop which imports the dict from `codes.py` which imports the functions from `sensors.py`.